Database appears as garbled characters in phpMyAdmin
I have a website in Arabic, and the website was displaying unreadable characters like Ø±Ø³Ø§Ø¦Ù„. I managed to fix the issue by changing the settings in MariaDB 10.6.19.
character_set_client       utf8mb4
character_set_connection   utf8mb4
character_set_database     latin1
character_set_filesystem   binary
character_set_results      utf8mb4
character_set_server       latin1
character_set_system       utf8mb3
character_sets_dir    /usr/share/mysql/charsets/

Now, the problem is that I cannot read the database in phpMyAdmin, as the Arabic text still appears as garbled characters.

That looks like Mojibake for "'رسائل".  Make sure the column in question is declared utf8mb4.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored  for further discussion and help.
